# Xcode not finding frameworks installed with pod install

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, ios-charts

I have a project that was working well until I manually installed ios-charts library. Now, Xcode can't find any of the frameworks I had running before.

[image: See the pod project in the workspace]

In the picture you can see the pod project in the workspace.

In the identity inspector the Pods_QM_Cons.framework is pointing to an empty folder in derived data. Sometime before, trying to work around an issue with the charts framework, I cleaned the derived data folder (deleted the contents), don't know it may have caused this.

I tried pod install a couple of times, even deleting the pod folder, pod.lock and workspace, but nothing works...

The actual error is no such module 'SVProgressHUD', one of the libraries...

I'd appreciate some help on this! it's driving me crazy...

Thanks

Comment: Thanks, I edited the question... The actual error is it can't find one of the modules... This has happened before and a simple build would fix it, but not this time...

Comment: SVProgressHUD is an ObjC lib, have you added it to your bridging header - or imported the framework at the top of your class?

Comment: I haven't, at least not manually, but it was working perfectly before, I have almost a month working with this, and it stoped working just now. But I'll read about the bridging header anyway...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, I think I solved the issue, by going to the build settings of the pod project, and setting "Build Active Architecture Only" to no for both debug and release. Debug was set to yes.

The question now would be how did it work until now, and why it failed... But the thing works...

Thanks!

Comment: Lifesaver man!  Thanks a million.  I had to do this for my Pod project and my main project.

Comment: Glad I could help!